# effective procedures in general

Tags: logic, computability

Any Godel numbering must be effective.  Given a number, there should be an effective procedure to determine whether it numbers a formula or proof, and, if it does, what it numbers.  Similarly, given a formula or proof, there should be an effective procedure to determine its Godel number.  However, effectiveness is normally defined as a property of functions on the natural numbers.  How, then, does one define effectiveness in general such that a Godel numbering counts?  Thanks!

Comment: Formulas and proofs are countable, so you can just enumerate them.

Comment: Thanks!  But countability implies the existence of a one-to-one function from the language into N.  What does it mean to say that such a function is effective (given that effectiveness concerns functions from N to N)?

Comment: The *effectiveness* is ensured by the fact that the alphaber of the language is countable and we may easily specify the rule for encoding any string. Simplified example : "$\forall$" is $0$, "$($" is $1$, "**$0$**" is $3$, "$)$" is $4$ and so on up to $10$. Here we have a simple table. For the variables, add the rule : $10+i$ for "$v_i$" ($11$ is $v_1$, $12$ is $v_2$, etc.). In this way, we have an effective rule for encoding strings.

Comment: Thanks, Mauro!  If I understand you, you're saying that it's the existence of functions from external objects into N that allows us to talk "by courtesy" about the effectiveness of functions on those objects alone, despite the fact that effectiveness only strictly concerns functions from N to N.

Comment: You can also consider several alternative definitions of "effective procedure", like [Markov algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_algorithm) or [Semi-Thue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Thue_system) that works with strings and that have been shown to be [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Comment: "effective" just means "computable (by a Turing machine)".